# ASP.NET Version 4 Framework, External component has thrown an exception

Tags: asp.net

My web application under develoopment was running just ok until a few hours ago without any change from my side, I started receiving the error "External component has thrown an exception.". The error message is the same even if I open my other web applications which I have not touched for a long time. Any idea what causing this. See error below:

> External component has thrown an exception.
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.
>
> Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 
>   [HttpException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9036040
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258

Comment: If you have deployed website on server then try to restart IIS.

Comment: Hi Mitul, No I have not deployed.I am testing from the local VS 2010 inbuilt IIS for now....

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try to figure out the issue.  I don't exactly what might be the issue though.

1. Try to attach another instance of Visual studio to debug the exact cause.  Detailed step by step process is listed in the following link.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653950/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception

1. Check you web.config it has changed from your previous versions.  Once I updated to framework 4 it messed up the layout and caused an issue but not the same as yours.

Comment: I have compared my backed up Web-config and the current one, they match exactly....I am trying to use the VS debugger according to the link you sent above but it does nto seem to cater for Windows 7.

Comment: Try this one http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653950/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception

Comment: Hi , I managed to generate the dump...can can I share with you? because seems I need password to share with the link u sent me above

Comment: Yes You can share I can try it but not sure if I will be able to solve it.

Comment: hi, where can i upload the dump for u to see it

Comment: am following the issue @ http://forums.asp.net/t/1704958.aspx/6/10?SEHException+thrown+when+I+run+the+application , it appears there is an issue here

Comment: For anyone trapped in this error: Solution is http://forums.asp.net/t/1704958.aspx/8/10?SEHException+thrown+when+I+run+the+application Basically uninstalled Trusteer and it worked!!!

Comment: Great.  Jim You can answer your own question so others will benefit from it.  Your solution is hidden inside comments.